# when doing keyup or keydown, textbox gets value instead of label for jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

This is driving me nuts now. I've searched everywhere but none of the solution seems to work.

The autocomplete works fine with all the label value loaded correctly to the autocomplet dropdown. I can select any label value with mouse and the same value goes to the textbox. 
But when I used keyup or keydown to select the label, the textbox gets the value instead of label. 
For example, with this data,

```
[{"label":"Tom Smith","value":"1234"},{"label":"Tommy Smith","value":"12321"}]
```

on keydown if I select "Tom Smith", the textbox will get value "1234".

My autocomplete code looks like below:

```
 $('.autocompleteEval').autocomplete({
    source: '@Url.Action("autocompleteEvalList")',
    minLength: 2,

    select: function (event, ui) {
        debugger;
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);

        if (ui.item.value == "-1") {
            $('.autocompleteEval').val('');
            $('#EvaluatorAjax').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('.autocompleteEval').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#EvaluatorAjax').hide();
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    , change: function (event, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
            $('.autocompleteEval').val('');
        }
        else {
            $('.autocompleteEval').val(ui.item.label);
            $(this).attr('actionId', ui.item.values);
            $('#EvaluatorAjax').hide();
        }
    }

    , search: function (event, ui) {
        $('#EvaluatorAjax').css('visibility', '');
    }

    , response: function (event, ui) {
        $('#EvaluatorAjax').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }

}).focus(function (event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();        
    $('.autocompleteEval').val(ui.item.label);
    return false;
});
```

Any help/suggestion(maybe wire the keypress event to autocomplete, not sure) on this is very much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle or post your HTML?

Comment: Thanks for going through the issue. I got it working anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it working. Somehow missed the jQuery API .keyup() and .keydown() functions. I hope this helps some other person

The html code looks like this - `<input class="autocompleteEval ui-autocomplete-input" id=txtEvaluator/>`

The resolved code looks like this.

```
$('.autocompleteEval').autocomplete({
 source: '@Url.Action("autocompleteEvalList")',
 minLength: 2,

select: function (event, ui) {
    debugger;
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).val(ui.item.label);

    if (ui.item.value == "-1") {
        $('.autocompleteEval').val('');
        $('#EvaluatorAjax').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.autocompleteEval').val(ui.item.label);
        $('#EvaluatorAjax').hide();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
, change: function (event, ui) {
    if (!ui.item) {
        $('.autocompleteEval').val('');
    }
    else {
        $('.autocompleteEval').val(ui.item.label);
        $(this).attr('actionId', ui.item.values);
        $('#EvaluatorAjax').hide();
    }
}

, search: function (event, ui) {
    $('#EvaluatorAjax').css('visibility', '');
}

, response: function (event, ui) {
    $('#EvaluatorAjax').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}

}).keyup(function (event, ui) {
    if (ui.item.value == "-1") {
        $('.autocompleteEval').val('');
    }
    else {
        $('.autocompleteEval').val(ui.item.label);
    }
    return false;
}).keydown(function (event, ui) {
    if (ui.item.value == "-1") {
        $('.autocompleteEval').val('');
    }
    else {
        $('.autocompleteEval').val(ui.item.label);
    }
    return false;
}).focus(function (event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();        
    $('.autocompleteEval').val(ui.item.label);
    return false;
});
```